# Watchkit: watchos2 reply from sendMessage is very slow

Tags: ios, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I am working with watchOS2 app. My watch app performs some NSURLSession tasks(which is quite fast) and sends reply to the phone using Watch Connectivity. I am using `sendMessageData` to send request to phone and reply is sent after performing required tasks. But the response takes a lot of time to reach the watch. Is there any other approach which will give a faster response.

I had seen a similar question in:
[Why sending message from WatchKit extension to iOS and getting back a reply is so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678545/why-sending-message-from-watchkit-extension-to-ios-and-getting-back-a-reply-is-s)

In the answer it is said that "sendMessage is much more expensive method than other communication API those are provided by WCSession".

Which other communication APIS are faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get an immediate reply from the other side, then sendMessageData with a replyHandler is the best you are going to find.

Comment: Thank you. I too implemented sendMessageData for the very reason.